# How to return Laravel exception into JSON response

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-9

I want customize my Laravel exception handler to return some JSON response, but I get empty result, with 500 http error.

I try it like this

```
 public function register()
 {
    $this->renderable(function (Throwable $e) {
        $status = $e->getCode();
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        $data   = $e->getTrace();

        return response()->json(['status' => $status, 'message' => $message, 'data' => $data], $status ?? 400);
    });
 }
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Are you using it inside a ```try catch``` block?

Comment: Already try that in controller but some exception still return as default error page Laravel. So I try to override all exception in exception handler but that's what I get

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Comment: For testing I try delete a data with empty id, so the error says 'call to a member function delete() on null bla bla bla ... ', I want that return as JSON but after I override the handler I get an empty return with 500 http error

Comment: Based on your ```error``` message I can say you need modify your code. First you need check whether the user exist or not for example ```$user = User::findOrFail($id);``` if exist you can delete or you can handle the response however you want. The main thing I'm trying to say. You need to handle your logic based on the scenario.

Comment: yes I knew findorfail method, I intentionally do that to see if my code in handler is working or not. is my explanation not understanable ? I just want to override laravel default error handler